# Changing the name of "Settings" in Android

Tags: java, android, menu, settings

I just started Android programming and couldn't find the answer for my problem.
When I press menu button within my app, "Settings" option comes up.

What I want to do is either

> a) Replace "Settings" option name with something else;

OR

> b) Disappear "Settings" option altogether so that I can use another Activity

How can I do either one of these?

Comment: see `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and also the associated `menu.xml` file that was referenced in it, and the associated `strings.xml` file which was referenced in the menu! phew.

Answer (score 4):

In  `res/menu/main.xml` you will have

```
 android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Change in `res/values/strings.xml`

```
 <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>// change Settings to what you want
```

Comment: I added `android:onClick="preferencesClicked"` at the end of action_settings entry in main.xml and getting an error as:
Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler preferencesClicked in class MainActivity

However I declared preferencesClicked as `public void preferencesClicked(View view)` in my MainActivity class. Do you also know how can I fix this too?

Comment: @SarpKaya can't do like that in `menu/main.xml` Wrong

Comment: @SarpKaya there's already a method for the overflow menu - override `onOptionsItemSelected()` then check for the id of the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove settings..

remove `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your Activity..

and remove xml files in your `res/menu` folder

or if you want to change the name..

rename the settings name in `res/memu/main.xml`